# How to resize a picture using HTML5 canvas and then upload it to Google drive?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, google-apps-script

I want my code to select image , resize it and then upload it to a google drive folder..
I have no problem with the selecting and uploading file as it works fine but I cannot have the resizing code work in between.

I have the following code to upload images to a folder in google drive using Google script..

GS:

```js
function uploadFiles(form) {
  
  try {
    
    var dropbox = "STpics";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);
    var data = getData();
    var myName2 = form.sorp3;
    
  
   
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }
    
    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob); 
    file.setName(Mohd +".jpg");
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + xxxxx);
    
    
  } catch (error) {
    
    return error.toString();
  }
  
}
```

Html:

```html
<form id="myForm">

    <input type="file" name="myFile" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif" />  <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="upload" 
           onclick="this.value='uploading..'; 
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                    return false;">
</form>

<div id="output"></div>


<script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
        document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
        
    }
</script>


<div id="Message12"></div>
<div id="Message"></div>

 <script>
 
 
 
    function DataSaved(){    
    document.getElementById('Message').innerHTML = "sending...";
   <?var url = getScriptUrl();?> 
   window.open(
  '<?=url?>?page=2 ',
  '_top' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);
   
};
 </script>
```

I got many scrips of HTML5 canvas to resize images but I could not integrate it with the above working code!
 Any help is apprecited.

Answer (score 2):

1. First use [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37772752/12777835)   for **resize** and crop **image**
2. submit [hidden input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIAu3.png) to server then base 64 convert to image, please [see link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59848874/12777835)

> Hidden Input Auto generate after cropped or resized